# Cannot download file on client side (MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, file, model-view-controller, download

I do not get any response when i'm trying to download an excel file from the server to the client. I have the following code to do the same.

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string file = "testfile.xlsx";

    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/temp"), file);

    return File(fullPath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", file);
}
```

I tried changing the contenttype to "application/vnd.ms-excel", but still did not work.

**The code comes into this action but nothing happens after the return file is parsed.**

Ill also add the ajax call, for this action.

```
$('#Submit_Report').click(function (event) {
if (($('#txtReportMarket').val() == '') && ($('#txtReportPractice').val() == '')) {
            alert("Please enter a value to Generate Report based on!");
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ShareTemplate/GenerateReport/',
                data: "{ 'ReportPractice': '" + $('#txtReportPractice').val() + "','ReportMarket':'" + $('#txtReportMarket').val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data["FileName"]);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/ShareTemplate/Download/',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("download Successful!");
                            @*window.open('@Url.Content("~/ShareTemplate/Download")')*@
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            DisplayError('Failed to load the data.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The first ajax call is working fine and the file has been generated and stored. But the second ajax call is where the problem is and sometime radomly I get the success message from the second ajax call too, but still the fle is not downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the First `ajax` call `success`. Place the below code and remove remaining.

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("Download", "ShareTemplate")';
```